# Confirm and Completed Icon in dashboard simillar

Tags: icons, dashboard

I am working on UX for the dashboard as we have booking progressing as our step for a booking system

one thing I'm not sure with this 'CONFIRMED' and 'COMPLETED'

Confirmed as the user is confirmed to collect the car

Completed in the last system as it's finished when the user returns the car

at the moment I'm using
[image]

So I feel there is some alter way to use confirmed icon rather than a green tick in confirm widget as I prefer it on the completed widget

Comment: Just a side note, but those overlay icon colours are quite clashing. I would suggest the "in progress" icon has a solid background colour and is "less black" (orange & yellow might work, or dark blue). And the green tick could also do with a solid background circle too (to match the "in progress" icon).

Comment: Thanks for head up. as will look on it colour issue( i feel it's more clashing too)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the normal use is the check and double check icons

[image]   [image]

*Images from [thenounproject.com](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=check%20and%20double%20check)*

Comment: I supposed it does make sense at all. thanks for advice as I'm rookie UX. learn something new today :-)